# Android get data from server with Kotlin serialization

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

How to take the necessary information from the server response using serialization?

Example:

```json
"location": {
    "name": "London",
    "region": "City of London, Greater London",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "lat": 51.52,
    "lon": -0.11,
    "tz_id": "Europe/London",
    "localtime_epoch": 1683804215,
    "localtime": "2023-05-11 12:23"
}
```

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class WeatherModel(
    @SerialName("location")
    val location: Location
)

@Serializable
data class Location(
    @SerialName("name")
    val townName: String
)
```

Comment: You are mixing up Kotlin-Serializable and JSON here. You need to use a Parser like Gson or Jackson to parse the server answer.

Comment: @Thommy the *Kotlin serialization* library works with JSON (and other things but that's the standard). Have you read the docs OP? (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#json-decoding) You basically call `Json.decodeFromString<WeatherModel>` so it knows what type to decode as. Nested classes produce nested objects in the JSON (like your `Location` in the `WeatherModel`). If you're asking how to *only* use the `name` value in your `Location`, you can do `format = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }` and call `decodeFromString` on that